# How to use a 64bit call gate

Tags: assembly, x86-64

In intel software developer maunal, the call instruction support:

```
call r/m64
call m16:32
call m16:64
```

In the user code, if I want to transfer to ring 0 via a 64-bit call-gate with selector 47.
How to write the instruction in assembly using intel syntax?

Tested:

```
call far [mem]; wrong
call qword ptr [mem]; wrong
```

memory content:

```
[mem + 0]: qword 0x00
[mem + 8]: word 47
```

Comment: It's a long shot, but `tword ptr` is used to address ten byte structures (basically the 80-bit long double). Also some assemblers use `lcall` for long call.

Comment: I thought only interrupts and syscalls could transfer to ring zero? It wouldn't really be a security feature if simple calls could change it, after all.

Comment: No, call gate is an option to enter ring 0 from ring x(x > 0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct keyword to use is `fword ptr`. This will generate the `m16:32` variant, but since for call gates the offset is ignored and the full 64 bits of `RIP` will be loaded from the gate, this will be fine. However if you want to keep the `m16:64` pointer, then you will have to manually include a `REX` prefix, like `rex64 call fword ptr [mem]` or `rex.w call fword ptr [mem]`.

Comment: by the way, what's the meaning of 'call far [mem]', I found it's not equal to 'call fword ptr [mem]'.

Comment: Judging from the generated machine code, the `far` seems to be silently ignored and generates a near call in this case.